# How to read hive data from HDFS

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have hive warehouse in HDFS hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse.

I have a database mydb inside hdfs like hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db

How can I create a table & insert data into it using Pyspark

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Using hive context you will be able to create the table in Hive, Please see the below code to acheive that.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

//hivecontext
sqlCtx= HiveContext(sc)

//Loading a csv file into dataframe
spark_df = sqlCtx.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("./data/documents_topics.csv")

//registering temp table
spark_df.registerTempTable("TABLE_Y")

//Creating table out of an existing temp created from data frame table
sqlCtx.sql("CREATE TABLE TABLE_X AS SELECT * from TABLE_Y")

//creating a brand new table in Hive
sqlCtx.sql("CREATE TABLE SomeSchema.TABLE_X (customername string, id string, ts timestamp) STORED AS DESIREDFORMAT")
```

Hope you can understand with the comments in the code, let me know if you ran into issues.